# npm selenium does not see my chromedriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `selenium-webdriver` module on npm and my code is =

```js
const selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Builder, By, Key } = selenium;
(async() => {
    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome().set('chrome.binary', './drivers/chromedriver.exe')).build();
})();
```

It gives me the error `Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH.` I downloaded `chromedriver` then try both using `.withCapabilities`(that part is still inside the code above) and `export PATH=$PATH:` but both not worked still giving same error I have `chromedriver` in a folder called `drivers` and that folder is on same folder with my `index.js` file I think my path writing is wrong but I really don't know how to do it can someone help?

Comment: chrome.binary is a path to `chrome.exe`, not to chromedriver. Maybe this could help: https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-setup-selenium-on-node-environment-ee33023da72d

Answer (score 0):

As @Max Daroshchanka suggested in the comments section, first thing is that you must have the path to the executable chrome.exe for the "chrome.binary" option.

Secondly, I will suggest that you have the same version for chromedriver.exe and your chrome.exe. I faced the same issue because I was not having the same version.

Now the following is something that did not work for me. Could not be the case with you.

Thirdly, I will also suggest that instead of relying on the node.js (or any package manager's) library (this gets created when you perform npm install, for every dependency there is a /lib folder created that has the executable) to add the required chromedriver.exe file. What I mean is manually download the required version driver file from here:
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

and add this downloaded extracted path to the PATH env variable.